# Hit counter: To know the exact number of visits to the website

Tags: javascript, css, jsp, servlets

I have developed a web project in jsp and servlets along with html css and bootstrap 3 as a front end. I am trying to code a hit counter by using servlet but when the server restarts the hit counter initialises to zero. Though I know that in Real world there will be little scenarios when the server will be down. So should i store the hit counter in a database...

Answer (score 0):

You can store the hit counter in the database.

Override Servlet's `destroy()` method.

```
@Override
public void destroy() {
    //super.destroy();
   //Do you Database operations.
}
```

And get the hit counter again in Servlet's `init()` method from Database when the application/Server starts.